# Get ListBox selected value on form into Report's textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a multiselected listbox in a form. How do I put the selected item of listbox into textbox in the report, with comma separation of each value (if I select multiple items)?

I've tried to put these vba code, yet it not showing any value.

```
Option Compare Database
Function Item_IDs() As String
    Item_IDs = Mid(Item_IDs, 3)
End Function
Private Sub WorkType_List_Click()
    Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim i As Integer, count As Integer
    Dim Item_IDs As String
    Set MyDB = CurrentDb()
    count = 1
    For i = 0 To WorkType_List.ListCount - 1
        If WorkType_List.Selected(i) = True Then
            Item_IDs = Item_IDs & ", " & WorkType_List.Column(1, i)
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Item_IDs = Item_IDs()
    Debug.Print Item_IDs
End Sub
```

[Filter] is my form's name
[WorkType_List] is my listbox name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refer to multiple selected Items in a listbox in ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495257/refer-to-multiple-selected-items-in-a-listbox-in-ms-access)

Comment: Create a VBA function that builds a CSV string of selected items. Call function from textbox. Alternatively, bind listbox to a multi-value field (I NEVER use multi-value field).

Comment: I had used the reference, I had problem to call the function. Insted of using 'Private', I used 'Function' to call ItemsID.

Comment: If you are still having issue, edit question with new info or start a new question.

Comment: I've edited the question using the code which I've been trying to compile.

Comment: Last two lines of Sub are useless and the Function does nothing. Since you have the Sub behind form, use Sub to populate a textbox on form. `Me.tbxIDs = Item_IDs`. Then textbox on report can reference form textbox `=Forms!formname.tbxIDs`. Alternatively, put code in a Function behind report or in general module with modification to refer to form and call function in report textbox. Another alternative, save data to field and include field in report RecordSource.

Comment: And another approach is to normalize data structure. Save selected items as individual records in a dependent table.

Comment: I use the first option and it works, thanks! @June7